# How to access multiple CiviCRM website fields for a contact in Drupal Views?

Tags: drupal-views

I have two website fields for my contacts, a work website and a personal website.  I am creating user profile pages (NOT CiviCRM profiles) for each of our members and want to display both website links, but, when I try to add a website field to the view, there is just one option to choose from and it is labelled generically, rather than as either personal or work.

How do I access both website fields?

When I add fields to the view for email or physical address, in the 'Configure field' dialogue in Views, there is a select box to choose which 'location type' you want for your email.

However, I don't get that option with websites.

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in your CiviCRM tab -> you can set the Number of Email fields to 2 -
  and then set one to Email Location: home and one to Email Location:
  work (and decide which one is primary). Save Settings.
- next: in your Webform Tab -> go ahead and hit Edit on the Elements
  you've just created -> change the Label to anything you want -> so
  that the user knows which Email address to plug in - in which field.
- in Views -> to create a Member listing. First of all make sure you
  have CMS database integration enabled -> check:
  civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1 - and follow the Views integration
  settings instructions
- then into Views -> make a View to display e.g. Contacts -> then add
  Fields for Email -> once you have added the field you can hit Edit
  and specify which one you'd like -> make that Primary or Work or
  Home. Add another Field for Email -> select another Location Type.
  That way you'll have multiple Email columns of different Location
  Type.

PS - just realized you said website -> but the recipe should be identical;

**EDIT:** - ah it's not - I just checked and it looks like Views integration is not quite working for that specific field yet (or it's a bug). Your workaround would be to store these fields yourself - in custom fields. Then you have complete control over them in both webform_civicrm as well as in views listings. I'll file an issue on JIRA

**EDIT:** reported: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19258

Comment: Thanks, Karin. This is precisely what I have been doing, but when I get to the 'Configure field' dialogue for the website field, there is no select box allowing me to choose which website type I want.

Comment: ah - I just checked and it looks like Views integration is not quite working for that specific field yet. Your workaround would be to store these fields yourself - in custom fields. Then you have complete control over them in both webform_civicrm as well as in views listings.

Comment: Brilliant.  That's what I needed to know.  Easily solved now.  Any reason you know of for why that field isn't working? Should you add your comment to your answer above and then let me mark it as the answer? Should I now answer my own question with your comment?  Do we leave this answer in the comments and I mark your answer as having solved my problem? Not sure what the proper procedure is here.

Comment: I'll add that - and I'll file a Views Integration issue on JIRA

Comment: Ok - done (see above) - that's probably the answer - for now.

Comment: Yep, the views code lacks the finesse required. we have in past just avoided using the civi core website fields and made up some custom ones for this exact reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I proposed some changes in the code to be able to choose the location and the type of the website here : https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19274

Comment: Thanks.  That's going to be excellent.  I've used custom fields for now and all is working well.

Answer (score 1):

Lewis, I would check out using [webform-civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) to do this, and a bunch of other handy stuff as well. In the CiviCRM tab, add the member as Contact 1 and of type Existing Contact. Then, in the fields to display for Contact 1, select Websites and choose to display two - work and personal.

[image]

Then edit the display label in the Webform tab for each displayed Website field and change to Website - Work and Website - Personal. You can have as many website, e-mail, address etc fields displayed (and updatable) as you like.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  I am certainly using webform-civicrm to collect the data on my drupal site.  What I want to do now is display it in member profiles.  For that, I'm using views in panels.  The issue is I can't 'find' the different webpage fields when I go to add fields to the view.  There is a generic webpage field to add, but not the list of ones I've created.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. I'm suggesting you use webform-civicrm to create a 'profile' of sorts.

Comment: Right.  How will that then help me display those fields later?  Thanks.

Comment: Lewis, are each of the members a user in CiviCRM? Or are you planning to have a public, searchable list of your members? If not, and members are logging in to view their own info, then point them to the webform, the member logs in and can see their own info displayed, and can also update the info, if you choose to allow that.

Comment: You can choose to display as many of the website fields as you like, by type. Increase the number to display in the CiviCRM tab of the webform.

Comment: Lewis, please see the update my answer, above.

Comment: From two comments up.  I am wanting to create a public list of members, so I can't use the form to display the fields.

Comment: Aha, OK then :) . That's different than the profile you wrote about in the question.

Comment: My apologies.  I realise now what went wrong.  Will edit the OP.  I was talking about a user info page type thing, not a CiviCRM profile.  My bad.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Lewis, no problem. I think you can get what you want with a combo of a view and a webform. To do that, I'll defer to KarenG for advice.