# Access Instant Messaging in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I want to display in Drupal Views the IM details, I think it could be displayed like the websites or phone details.

Should I add it to CiviCRM or is it something civicrm_entity should handle ?

Answer (score 2):

I added the feature in CiviCRM, 
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19274

Answer (score 0):

I needed some more changes in the relationships, to be able to display the phone of the household of the contact :

in the relationships :

- relationship CiviCRM relationship 'household member of'
- relationship household as contact_id_b
- relationship phone from relationship 'household', choice of primary phone

displayed fields : phone number, phone location, phone type from the 'Phone' relationship

so I altered some more code to be able to do that,

and I added the possibility to choose the location and type for Instant Messaging and Website, 
so it should answer [How to access multiple CiviCRM website fields for a contact in Drupal Views?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14529/how-to-access-multiple-civicrm-website-fields-for-a-contact-in-drupal-views?rq=1)

I will put it in the same PR because it's related to the same part of code (relationships and fields location-related).